# Java - print routes and cost

Tags: java, algorithm, search, a-star

I have an A* search algorithm in Java, I want it to be able to print the tours so the user can see which routes it has tried and which is the best route. At the minute it just prints the best route, which is fine, I want it to do that but I also want it to print a list of the routes so you can see the worst and associated cost for each.
From the code below if I print followedRoute that prints out every tour but can I print the cost of each? The algorithm works by finding each complete tour and the lowest cost of those, ideally I only want to print the complete tours so not {0}, {0, 3}, etc.

Below is the relevant code segment I believe, if you need to see anymore then please ask :)

---

```
Cities aux = currentCities;
ArrayList followedRoute = new ArrayList();
followedRoute.add(aux.number);
while (aux.level != 0) {
    aux = aux.parent;
    followedRoute.add(0, aux.number);
}

if (currentCities.level == distances.getCitiesCount()) {
    solution = true;
    bestRoute = followedRoute;
    bestCost = currentCities.g;
} else {
    for (int i=0; i<distances.getCitiesCount(); i++) {
        // have we visited this city in the current followed route?
        boolean visited = followedRoute.contains(i);
        boolean isSolution = (followedRoute.size() == distances.getCitiesCount())&&(i == firstNode);

        if (!visited || isSolution) {
            Cities childCities = new Cities(i, currentCities.g + distances.getCost(currentCities.number, i), 
                    getHeuristicValue(currentCities.level + 1), currentCities.level + 1);
            childCities.parent = currentCities;
            opened.add(childCities);  
            System.out.println(followedRoute);
        }
    }                
}
```

---

Any help is massively appreciated! Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I dont think A* works like that.. At best you can get the choices and the costs at each decision, but that is on choice of immediate connection

Comment: I see, but surely it works out the cost of each completed tour though in order for it to return the optimum tour?

Comment: Nope, It chooses the best route based on the heuristic function and the cost of the next jump essentially, which means that the decision is happening at each jump about the next jump, not at the end about all the different routes.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you are going to have a hard time modifying A* to do so, and it will be very inefficient<sup>1</sup>.

In fact, there is no known algorithm to do what you are after, it is called the [**longest path problem**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem), and it is [NP-Hard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-hard), so there is no known polynomial solution to it.

(For intuition why it is true - think of an algorithm that can find the longest simple path from a vertex `v` - given such algorithm - one can easily determine if there is a Hamiltonian Path from `v`, repeat the process to check if there is any [hamiltonian path](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path) in the graph. Since the [Hamiltonian Path Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path_problem) is NP-Hard, so does this problem.

One way to find the longest path is to use brute-force (search all possible paths). It can be achieved using a modification on [DFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) (that forgets 'visited' nodes), and recursively checks all paths in the graph - until all are exhausted - and returns the longest of them.

Sorry for the disappointing news, but I hope at least it won't make you spend time on things that are (most likely) cannot be done (efficiently).

---

(1) [Assuming P!=NP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P_versus_NP_problem), which is the common belief by most CS researchers.